# Extract data from .txt files and take those data in rows and column

Tags: python, python-3.x, rows

I have a set of datas from a .txt file in this format:

```
30     1
     2477.25     0.00    1                   M
40     2   11
        0.17100     0.08600     0.11500     0.10800     0.05600     0.07500 9.60000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000
        2.70000
36     1    1
   a.a.Sbargang
30     1
     2477.45     0.00    2                   M
40     2   11
      0.52100     0.27400     0.35900 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000    14.30000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000
      2.66000
36     1    1
   a.a M-gr.
```

The format is quite messy, and I want to make it in rows and columns so my output will be like this:

```
30 1 2477.25 0.00 1 M 40 2 11 0.17100 0.08600 0.11500 0.10800 0.05600  0.07500 9.60000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 2.70000 36 1 1 a.a.Sbargang
30 1 2477.45 0.00 2 M 40 2 11 0.52100 0.27400 0.35900 -1009.0 -1009.0 -1009.00 14.3000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 -1009.00000 2.66000 36 1 1 a.a M-gr.
```

I am quite new to python and not sure how to write python3 to do this task? Thanks in advance

I have tried to like this:

```
with open ('textdata3.txt') as f:
    inputString = f.read()

inputString = re.sub(r" +"," ", inputString)
itemInString = inputString.split(" ")

row1 = []
for index, item in enumerate(itemInString):
    if index % 1 == 0:
    row1.append(str(item))

print(row1)
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but here I get everything in 1 row.

Output:

```
['30', '1\n', '2477.25', '0.00', '1', 'M\n40', '2', '11\n', '0.17100', '0.08600', '0.11500', '0.10800', '0.05600', '0.07500', '9.60000', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000\n', '2.70000\n36', '1', '1\n', 'Sst.Lt-gry.F-gr.Sbang.VW-cmt.VP-srt.w/Mic.Calc.Glauc.\n30', '1\n', '2477.45', '0.00', '2', 'M\n40', '2', '11\n', '0.52100', '0.27400', '0.35900', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000', '14.30000', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000', '-1009.00000\n', '2.66000\n36', '1', '1\n', 'a.a', 'M-gr.']
```

Comment: What have you attempted or considered so far?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem. [i voted to close your question because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) you do not show any effort you made.

Comment: Does it need to be in Python?  Or would GNU sed `N;N;N;N;N;N;s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g` be acceptable?

Comment: I'm trying learn Python, so Python would be preferred over GNU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data is consistently grouped in blocks of seven lines this should work.

```
import re
rows = []
with open("input_data.txt", "rb") as input_file:
    while True:
        try:
            row = [str(next(input_file), "utf-8") for x in xrange(7)]
            rows.append(re.sub( '\s+', ' ', " ".join(row)))
        except StopIteration as e:
            break

with open("reformatted_data.txt", "wb") as out_file:
    for row in rows:
        out_file.write(row+"\n")
```

Updated version based on the comments below.

```
import re
rows = []
with open("data.txt", "rb") as input_file:
    row = []
    while True:
        try:
            data = str(next(input_file))
            data = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', data).strip()
            if data == "30 1":
                rows.append(" ".join(row))
                row = []

            row.append(data)

        except StopIteration as e:
            rows.append(" ".join(row))
            break

with open("reformatted_data.txt", "wb") as out_file:
    for row in rows:
        out_file.write(row+"\r\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Karl Graham, but when I try to run the code I get this error message:     rows.append(re.sub( '\s+', ' ', " ".join(row)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found. I'm not sure how to fix the error.

Comment: Apologies, I was testing in a python 2.7 environment. I'm currently unable to test the code in python 3 but I think the edit above has fixed the issue.

Comment: I've set the encoding to utf-8 as an example but that will have to be changed to match the encoding of your data.

Comment: Thanks again, I found out in your code it was open with binary mode with 'rb', when I changed to 'r' your first code worked fine. Again thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you. But if the data is not consistantly, example if the block is in six block of lines and some are in seven. Is there a way to write the code for that?

Comment: In the data is there a consistent final value that could be tested against? E.g. in the two examples above they both end in a string whereas all the other values are floats/ints.

Comment: In some data it ends with a letter and in other data it ends with a number. So i'm not sure if its a way to test the end value of those line.

Comment: What about the beginning of the groups? The two examples above both start with 30 1.

Comment: Yeah, I just read most of my data and it does start with 30    1, so I can use those values to test against?

Comment: I've added an updated version of the script to the answer which based on my testing seems to produce the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when exporting data since I ended up with a massive column and then needed to break that massive columns to reproduce the original structure. This chunk of code solved my problem:

```
def arrumando_dados():
    #defining a path to the file
    path_to = glob.glob('.../txts/*.txt')

    #creating an empty dictionary
    idl_results = {}

    #looping over the files
    for i in range(0,len(path_to)):

        #creating a variable with the appropriated name
        #that will only work if the numbers are positioning the cropping
        #correctly
        var_name = path_to[i][-6:-4]

        #taking the data with numpy
        data2 = np.loadtxt(path_to[i])

        #break lines every 949 items
        new_data = np.array(np.array_split(data2,949))

        #fixing for the idl vs python display
        new_data_t = np.matrix.transpose(new_data)

        #updating the dictionary
        idl_results.update({var_name: new_data_t})

    return(idl_results)
```

Then I think that with some adjustments you can use this bit of code to solve your problem.